# Wrong default site

Tags: multi-site, plugin-recaptcha

I want to use the [recaptcha plugin](https://github.com/clarknelson/craft-recaptcha-3)
but I get a JS error because the script is looking at the wrong site. The plugin is using

> scoreRequest.open("POST", "/{{ craft.app.config.general.actionTrigger
> }}/craft-recaptcha-3/default", true);

which brings to
https://xxxx.com/en/actions/craft-recaptcha-3/default/
instead of
https://xxxx.com/fr/actions/craft-recaptcha-3/default/

EN is still installed but disabled as we are only using FR at the moment. FR is already checked as the primary site in the settings... Why is it still using /en/ and how can I fix this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

the dev fixed it and released a new version. Thank you!